# Load Social Media Script after Ajax Load

Tags: php, ajax, icons

I'm trying to add the following syntax to existing page in order to add the social media icon (linkedin, fb and twitter) into the page, but always bumped and it's not showing on the page.

I'm new especially for ajax and I don't know where is my mistake, I just want to load the icon on the end of the news.

Here are my code

```
<!--SEA New Add-->
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").live("runScripts", function(){
        $(init);    

        function init() {
            $.get('news-sharesocial.html', inject);
        }

        function inject(data) {
            debugger;
            $('.news_sharesocial').html(data);
            //$('body').html(data);
            //document.write(data);
        }
    });

    $('.news_sharesocial').trigger("runScripts"); 
    //$("body").trigger("runScripts"); 

});
</script>
```

NOTE:

- I put the code on the end of the page since this is only for news and this is a template.

Appreciate any help on this, I've been strugling with this for quite some time. 
Thank you very much

-sea-

Answer (score 0):

Very first thing you are using very old version of jQuery and live is deprecated tag in newer version.

Second you need to modify the code as below where  you need to trigger event attach to body not to 
news_sharesocial

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("body").live("runScripts", function(){
    $(init);    

    function init() {
        $.get('news-sharesocial.html', inject);
    }

    function inject(data) {
        debugger;
        $('.news_sharesocial').html(data);
        //$('body').html(data);
        //document.write(data);
    }
});
$("body").trigger("runScripts"); 
});
```

As you have attached the event to body so it will be triggered from same element.